# Custom Pinterest button for custom URL (Text-Link, Image, or Both)

Tags: html, css, pinterest

I tried to find the solution but can't. I need a custom image for Pinterest (Pin It) button and pin some custom image by url but not a current page.

I created a custom link:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://inspired-ui.com&media={ImageURL}&description=DescriptionText" class="pinitbutton">Pin It</a>
```

in style I set the background image but I see only default Pin It button and not my custom button

There are some solutions where you can set custom button image for Pin It button but I can't change the media={ImageURL} in those solutions.

The popular solution is

```
<a href='javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement(&apos;script&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;type&apos;,&apos;text/javascript&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;charset&apos;,&apos;UTF-8&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;src&apos;,&apos;http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r=&apos;+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());'><img src='http://www.brandaiddesignco.com/blog/PinIt.png'/></a>
```

But it doesn't help me. Does any one know the solution?

Comment: Any solutions how to do that?

Answer (score 21):

Indeed the popular solution by *Jeremy Mansfield* at [www.brandaiddesignco.com](http://www.brandaiddesignco.com/blog/add-a-custom-pinterest-pin-it-button-to-your-website/375/) has a great method to customize the Pinterest button **any way you want**!

I've made **three examples**, in the form of **jsFiddle's**, so you can see how it's done using that method.

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle Text-Link method**](http://jsfiddle.net/hUAh8/1/) 
**Reference:** [**jsFiddle Custom Logo method**](http://jsfiddle.net/hUAh8/2/) 
**Reference:** [**jsFiddle Custom Logo and Image method**](http://jsfiddle.net/hUAh8/3/)

For more **Pinterest Info**, see my other [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11253923/1195891).

Comment: Heads up: this is for the old pinterest button.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ben Polinsky. These old jsFiddle examples are for webpages still using [http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js](http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js) instead of the newer [http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js](http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js) JavaScript files. For more info on the NEW Pinterest Pin It Button, see the [official webpage](https://developers.pinterest.com/pin_it/). Once the old method is no longer supported by Pinterest, I'll remove this answer. Cheers!

Comment: This is the only working solution out of all of the above. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: **2016**: Here is my cleaned up version that supports both HTTP/HTTPS, latest version of jQuery, and both the text method and image method listed above. https://jsfiddle.net/prrstn/Lh5b5upb/

Comment: @PrestonBadeer, thanks for the comment, and since some users will auto scroll to the most recent answer, consider posting this comment and/or your jsFiddle as an answer too, in which case I will upvote it. To be sure, your jsFiddle stands on it's own nicely.

Comment: @arttronics Thanks for the suggestion, I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 21):

Adding an encoded whitespace before the last fragment of the URL will prevent Pinterest's JS from "hijacking" the link:

```
//pinterest.com/pin/create/%20button?url=
```

**Update:**

It seems that my previous solution doesn't work anymore. Here is another one:

```
//pinterest.com/pin/create%2Fbutton/?url=
```

Comment: This causes the pins to fail for me.

Comment: This will work (just tested 5 minutes ago)... but you'll also have to provide what they say is an "image_url" parameter. Their notification is lying, you have to use "media" and it'll work.

So, /?url=mysite.com&amp;media=mysite.com/whatever-image.jpg

Comment: I'm using the second option with "media" and its working for me. It has stopped the Pinterest JS from taking over my link, Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

At the risk of over simplifying things, use your `'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='` path that you've already got, set up your variables, and append them as you do, and just don't include any pinterest javascript. Without that js, it won't find the link and replace it out with their own pinterest button. Just customize your link with an image inside it (or set a background image or whatever) and screw the pinterest js. Set the target to open in a new window.

Comment: This simplified the process SO much.  Why didn't I think of that before...  Thank you!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the insight. Could you possibly provide an example? I think this would be really helpful.

Comment: @MichaelSmith I could... but to be honest, the answer by rharvey is probably better because it's more robust. If you still want a non-js example, let me know and I'll type it out.

Answer (score 15):

Custom Link/Button looks like this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312923/custom-pinterest-button-for-custom-url-text-link-image-or-both" data-image="http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.sstatic.net%2Fstackexchange%2Fimg%2Flogos%2Fso%2Fso-logo.png" data-desc="Custom Pinterest button for custom URL (Text-Link, Image, or Both)" class="btnPinIt">
    Custom Pin it image or text here!
</a>
```

Note: I don't think the data attributes need to be encoded (like I did for data-image) but it doesn't seem to hurt it.

JQuery:

```
$('.btnPinIt').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var media = $(this).attr('data-image');
    var desc = $(this).attr('data-desc');
    window.open("//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"+
    "?url="+url+
    "&media="+media+
    "&description="+desc,"_blank");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: works.  simple and lightweight.  i also added the following parameters to the window.open call to more closely resemble the oob pinterest pop up window...
,"toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=0, right=0, width=750, height=320"

Comment: There seems to be an issue with this. This solution opens 2 windows whenever I click on the pinterest link.

Comment: That's strange Michael, I just tested it and it still seems to work. See this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wtjfcyuw/

Comment: Not sure why this is happening on my side. I read that the "return false" should prevent another window from popping up. I ultimately had to set a target prevent this from happening.

Comment: Also, It might be worth passing in the event object into the function and calling event.preventDefault() see updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wtjfcyuw/1/

Answer (score 6):

Here is what worked for me :

```
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-custom="true"><img src="../img/custompinint.png" /></a>
```

The attribute data-pin-custom is what I picked up from [Pinterest documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/pin-it/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be the current accepted answer. Pinterest added support for this (`data-pin-custom`) as it was a frequently requested feature.

Comment: This worked for me except I used a text link rather than an `<img>`

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of trial and error, below is what worked for me. This response is a combination of @rharvey's response thread and another stack overflow post. This solution opens up a pop up to share content via pinterest.

Note: In order to prevent 2 windows from popping up you need to set a target. Below is the full solution:

```
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312923/custom-pinterest-button-for-custom-url-text-link-image-or-both" data-image="http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.sstatic.net%2Fstackexchange%2Fimg%2Flogos%2Fso%2Fso-logo.png" data-desc="Custom Pinterest button for custom URL (Text-Link, Image, or Both)" class="btnPinIt" target= "pinIt">
    Custom Pin it image or text here!
</a> 

<script>
$('.btnPinIt').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var media = $(this).attr('data-image');
    var desc = $(this).attr('data-desc');
    window.open("//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"+
    "?url="+url+
    "&media="+media+
    "&description="+desc,"pinIt","toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=0, right=0, width=750, height=320");
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Works very nicely!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me perfectly.
Your script

```
 <script>
    function pinIt()
    {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
      e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');
      e.setAttribute('src','https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);
      document.body.appendChild(e);
    }
    </script>
```

Call it with

```
<a href="javascript:pinIt();">Pin</a>
```