# Why can't I use a non-stock Pin it button?

Tags: javascript, html, pinterest

This is probably my least code oriented question, but I can't get this to work at all. I'm trying to use a square .png for a pin it button instead of the stock button pinterest provides.

Here is my code implementing the button:

```
var twit = 'http://twitter.com/home?status='+title+'%20'+url;
var facebook = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+url
var linkedIn = 'https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url='+url+'&amp;title='+title;
var gPlus = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='+url+'&amp;title='+title;
var pinterest = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/?url=' + url + '&amp;title=' + title;

var tbar = '<div id="socializethis"><span>Share<br /><a href="#min" id="minimize" title="Minimize"> <img src="/images/minimize.png" /> </a></span><div id="sicons">';
tbar += '<a href="'+twit+'" id="twit" title="Share on twitter"><img src="/Content/images/twitter.png"  alt="Share on Twitter" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
tbar += '<a href="'+facebook+'" id="facebook" title="Share on Facebook"><img src="/Content/images/facebook.png"  alt="Share on facebook" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
tbar += '<a href="'+linkedIn+'" id="linkedIn" title="Share on Linked In"><img src="/Content/images/linkedIn.png"  alt="Share on Linked In" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
tbar += '<a href="'+gPlus+'" id="gPlus" title="Share on Google plus"><img src="/Content/images/gPlus.png"  alt="Share on Google Plis" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
tbar += '<a href="'+pinterest+'" id="pinterest" title="Share on pinterest"><img src="/Content/images/pint.png"  alt="Share on pinterst" width="32" height="32" /></a>';
tbar += '</div></div>';
```

I'm creating a pull out for square icons, so it's a bunch of html strings that javascript appends to the document.

The other sites' button work just fine, the pinterest one always turns the button into their own button.  I've tried playing around with the url, or any script that could be on my site for this but no matter what, for it to link to the proper url it turns into the stock button.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'd expect it's a 3rd-party script that's doing this. Images don't just magically change themselves, so whatever your "socalizethis" thing is, it must look at your links and modify the image inside the Pinterest one. It's possible it's a term of use of Pinterest that requires you to use their image - you may want to look into that.

Comment: nope. Socialize this is the name of the menu.  It's a bunch of html string, static imgs and it appends all of it to the dom.  It's only on pinterest's end that things change.  None of the other sites give me this problem, I do not have any pinterest scripts on my site, and it only changes the image when I have the url: http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url...

Comment: It could be that the URL /create/button is actually creating and overwriting the img src of the pin button and replacing it with the src that they generate, have you checked the src on the img link? does it change? if it does you could overwrite it again once the page has finished loading or look at the documentation someone must know why it does this. Maybe you can use another URL that's used for custom pins.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at this question on stackoverflow? [Custom Pinterest button for custom URL (Text-Link, Image, or Both)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312923/custom-pinterest-button-for-custom-url-text-link-image-or-both). There's three links that could help you out and another link to another question about custom pinterest pins. Check it out hope it helps!

Comment: I already tried that solution, however the way it is writen into the <a> won't allow it to work in javascript.