# Pinterest: data-pin-description not overriding title / description tags

Tags: pinterest

We are using the data-pin-description tag inside the images but it's not overriding the title tag on the image and even if we remove the tags on the image, if the page has markup tags for the description (such as og:description) the data-pin-description is completely ignored. What are we doing wrong and how can we force Pinterest to override the descriptions?

For example in the sample below when visitors click on the Pinit button the description it shows is 'Granite Green, Hot/Cold Bulk Food Holding Cabinet'

```
<img src="/images/enlarged/CMBH1826-192.jpg" data-pin-id='4107' data-pin-description='The cabinet body is a tough, one-piece seamless double-wall polyethylene shell that is easy to maintain and clean and wont dent, crack, rust, chip or break. Model: CMBHC1826LF-192 by Cambro' title="Granite Green, Hot/Cold Bulk Food Holding Cabinet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your button link you can add the description as a parameter, e.g.:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?description=DescriptionText" data-pin-save="true">Pin It</a>
```

source - Sergey, [Custom Pinterest button for custom URL (Text-Link, Image, or Both)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312923/custom-pinterest-button-for-custom-url-text-link-image-or-both?noredirect=1&lq=1)