# Pinterest share without pin it button

Tags: javascript, button, pinterest

Can I create pinterest share without pin it button? I had try using these but it seem fail.

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=google.com">Pin it</a>

<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=google.com">Pin it</a>
```

Is there any way I can create a pinterest share link without pin it button?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690019/link-to-pin-it-on-pinterest-without-generating-a-button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making your hyperlink url like this, this worked for me

```
string url = "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" +
        "?url=" + "your link" +
        "&media=" + "link to youre image" +
        "&description=" + "your description";
```

both media and description can be blank so you could do

```
string url = "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" +
        "?url=" + "" +
        "&media=" + "" +
        "&description=" + "";
```

to test it out

in my code im calling a redirect after a button press but i think this should work for you.

Comment: Close. Replace /button/ with /link/

Comment: New final Url to post is `https://pinterest.com/pin-builder/?url=YOUR-URL&media=IMAGE-URL&description=YOUR-DESCRIPTION`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a 
        data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" 
        data-pin-lang="en"
        href={`https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=${anyHttpsURL}&medial=${anyHttpsImageURL}&description=${encodeURIComponent(pinterestDescription)}`} 
    >
      <Image src={PinterestIcon} /> Pinterest
    </a>
```