# How to open Pinterest button in a separate window?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

i'm using this little bit of code to add a 'pin it' button to my wordpress site. I added in target=
"_blank" and it still opens in same window.

```
<a target="_blank" href='javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement(&apos;script&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;type&apos;,&apos;text/javascript&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;charset&apos;,&apos;UTF-8&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;src&apos;,&apos;//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r=&apos;+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());'>Pin it</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pinterest have a [button generator](https://business.pinterest.com/en/widget-builder#do_pin_it_button) which is probably the easiest and recommended way to do this.
But if you're much more inclined to do this via link you can try this..

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=[yourURLHere]" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">Pin it</a>
```

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690019/link-to-pin-it-on-pinterest-without-generating-a-button) for more info.
By the way, you might want to read this [documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/pin_it/), just to be aware of possible consequences if you go this route.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option you can try. Bear in mind that this requires JQuery. So make sure that it's included on your page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

here is your solution:

```
<a href="http://example.com" rel="external">External link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a[rel="external"]').attr('target', '_blank');
</script>
```

Notice the `rel="external"` that was added to the link

Comment: 2020 here, no jquery required for this