# "Parameter 'image_url' (value http:null) is not a valid URL format."

Tags: sharing, pinterest

I'm working on a project involving sharing to Pinterest, but I'd prefer not to use their JS library.  I expected to just need a link like "https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fimages%2Fsrpr%2Flogo11w.png", but I'm getting an error stating "Parameter 'image_url' (value http:null) is not a valid URL format."  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: were you able to find a fix for it?

Comment: I ended up trying again and specifying the image as `media` and the page as `url` and it seemed to work, though I'm not sure why.

Comment: Good thoughts over here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690019/link-to-pin-it-on-pinterest-without-generating-a-button

Comment: I had it working without the `media` arg (it would look at `og:image` at the source url) but it seems to have regressed and now I need to put in a `media` arg or else I get the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

i'm faced the same problem and solved changing `image_url` for `img_url`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).